# Create a subtitle mpd file with MP4box

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle, video-player, mp4box, mpd

I'm creating a mpd file for a video player and for now I have everything to cover the video, audio and language settings but I'm struggling with the subtitles.

Here's the command I used for audio and video :

```
mp4box -dash 10000 -profile dashavc:264:onDemand -rap video/audio.mp4#audio/video
```